# Array declared without size and const volatile

Tags: c, arrays, constants, volatile, extern

I found this line in my work project, but I can't understand this:

```
extern const volatile uint8 * const volatile array[];
```

Could you please help me explain the line?

Comment: Does not look like standard C..but provide more context

Comment: btw `cconst` is a typo?

Comment: An incomplete array of constant pointer to constant `uint8_t`? I am not sure how `const` and `volatile` go together in a sane way., but well ... probably an embedded environment.

Comment: a definition with `volatile` make shure, that the variable will not be removed by any optimization of the compiler; that is necessary, e.g. when you address a register on a microprocessor aso.

Comment: `array[]` in this context means a pointer to an array. As there was already a pointer, it now is a double pointer. Am I correct?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie "`array[]` in this context means a pointer to an array" No. BTW, we don't know anything about the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, leaving out the qualifiers:

```
uint8 *array[];
```

`array` is an array of unspecified size whose elements are of type `uint8 *`.  In other words, an array of pointers to `uint8`.

If this declaration appears as a parameter to a function, the array syntax is actually shorthand for a pointer.  If it is not a function parameter and is declared at file scope then this acts as a **tentative definition**.  A complete definition may occur elsewhere in the code that specifies the size and optionally an initializer.  If no other complete definition exists, then the array is defined to have 1 element.

Before talking about what the declaration means with the qualifiers, let's first talk about exactly what those qualifiers mean.

The `const` qualifier prevents code from modifying the named object.  Given this declaration:

```
const int x;
```

It means that `x` can't be modified using for example `x = 1`.  With pointers involved it's a little more tricky:

```
const int *x;
```

This defines `x` as a pointer to a `const int`.  That means that you can modify `x` but not what it points to.  So `x = &y` is legal but not `*x = 1`.

```
int * const x;
```

This defines `x` as a `const` pointer to an `int`, which means you can't modify `x` but you can modify what it points to.  So `x = &y` is not legal but `*x = 1` is.

```
const int * const x;
```

This defines `x` as a `const` pointer to a `const int`.  So in this case, neither `x` nor what it points to can be modified.

```
const int * const x[];
```

Here, `x` is an array whose elements are `const` pointers to a `const int`.  As in the prior example, for each array element, neither the array element nor what it points to can be modified.

Now let's talk about `volatile`.  This qualifier tells the compiler that  the variable  in question might change unpredictably.  From section 6.7.3p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> An  object  that  has  volatile-qualified  type  may  be  modified  in
>   ways  unknown  to  the implementation  or  have  other  unknown  side 
>   effects.   Therefore any expression  referring to such an object shall
>   be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine,
>   as described in 5.1.2.3.  Furthermore, at every sequence point the
>   value last stored in the object shall agree with that prescribed by
>   the abstract machine, except as modified by the unknown  factors 
>   mentioned  previously. <sup>134)</sup> What  constitutes  an  access  to  an 
>   object  that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined
>
> 134) A `volatile` declaration  may  be  used  to  describe  an  object 
>   corresponding  to  a  memory-mapped input/output  port  or  an  object
>   accessed  by  an  asynchronously  interrupting  function.   Actions 
>   on objects  so  declared  shall  not  be  "optimized  out"  by  an 
>   implementation  or  reordered  except  as permitted by the rules for
>   evaluating expressions

What this means is that a `volatile` object could change in ways not known to the compiler, and thus the compiler should not perform any optimizations on this variable and in fact should assume the value was changed externally.

Now moving on the your full declaration:

```
const volatile uint8 * const volatile array[];
```

This declares `array` as an array of unspecified size whose elements are of type `uint8 *`, where the elements of the array cannot be modified by the program (i.e. are `const`) but could be modified externally (i.e. `volatile`), and what those array elements point to also cannot be changed by the program but could be modified externally.

Comment: Nice answer:) one nitpick, depending on where `array` is defined it might be considered an array of 1 element, and specifically since this doesn't have the `extern` qualifier.

Comment: @nullp0tr That behavior is non-standard.  Some compilers support that as an extension but not all.

Comment: If at the end of the translation unit containing
`int i[];`
the array `i` still has incomplete type, the implicit initializer causes it to have one element, which is set to zero on program
startup.
That's what the standard says.

Comment: @nullp0tr On some compilers, not all.  gcc will accept it but not MSVC.

Comment: then it's standard behavior that some compilers don't support and not vice versa.

Comment: @nullp0tr I don't see anything in the standard stating that.  Please provide the section / paragraph number from the standard that supports your claim.

Comment: [C17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) draft, § 6.9.2,  External object definitions.

Comment: @nullp0tr I stand corrected.  I wasn't able to find that passage.  I'll update to reflect.

Comment: Corrected, I use gcc compiler. Thank for you answer.